# iTunes on two computers (with last.fm) loses track of iPhone metadata

Tags: iphone, itunes, sync

Connecting an iPhone to my work PC that is synced with home PC causes minor but annoying breakage for me. It seems to do a small sync of some sort then lose track marks etc:

I have an iPhone synced (automatically) with my home PC, where I also have scrobbling enabled. I also plug in my iPhone at work, to charge and scrobble if I haven't connected at home for a while.

When I plug in at work there is some kind of small sync that occurs ("Sync in Progress") and the automatically sync when connected box is checked. My understanding is that this box is a iPhone property, not a local iTunes one, and that unchecking it will stop automatic sync happening at home. After the connection, things tend to be wrong:

1. sometimes scrobbling doesn't work, sometimes things are scrobbled but **duplicated** when plugging in at home, sometimes things are scrobbled that **haven't** been listened to recently.
2. iPod regularly **loses track marks, now playing, marks podcasts as new** when they aren't etc.
3. sometimes iPod takes a long time to display library after being disconnected, **as if it has been corrupted**.

Should I have things setup differently?

I was going to ask what the state of play is with general purpose iTunes-at-home-and-work solutions (note: iTunes 9 doesn't really solve this as far as I can tell: no metadata, ripped music etc.); I get the impression no easy (especially non-third-party) solutions exist still. **Is there at least a combination of settings that allow hassle-free use of my work PC to charge and scrobble the device, even if not keeping the libraries perfectly in sync?** I would of course be more than happy if someone added getting fresh podcasts too ;P (or general purpose total sync!)

Comment: I only use iTunes on one machine (a MacBook) to sync my iPhone and Last.fm scrobbling still messes up. I've come to the conclusion that it's just kindof rubbish. 

Oh yes, and I get the watched/unwatched status of podcasts messed up sometimes as well. Don't think that's related to the scrobbler though.

Comment: I'm willing to accept scrobbling as a red herring, but losing watched/unwatched status and track positions seems to happen 100% of the time attaching to a second computer, and never otherwise. For me, that is.